# sender dependent default transport maps

Tags: postfix

I have around 6 Ips and 6 email addresses I want to make sure that every email address uses the Ip that I allow it to send email I added this command in the end of main.cf sender dependent default transport maps

```
care@    smtp:192.236.11
care1@    smtp:192.236
care2@    smtp:192.236
care3@    smtp:192.236
care4@    smtp:192.236
care5@    smtp:192.236
```

But now the email is being sent back to me I am getting error like
This is the mail system at host host.com

> I'm sorry to have to inform you that your message could not
> be delivered to one or more recipients. It's attached below.
>
> For further assistance, please send mail to postmaster.
>
> If you do so, please include this problem report. You can
> delete your own text from the attached returned message.
>
> ```
>               The mail system
> ```

`<test-irn29i3nb@srv1.mail-tester.com>: mail for 192.236.11` loops back to
myself

Comment: Do you try to limit those IP as Postfix clients restricting to send from corresponding FROM address? Transport map is the destination points where postfix send emails after it was accepted for delivery.